# Understanding ReferenceProperty backend behavior in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to understand a basic use case of working with GAE db.ReferenceProperties.

#### Example:

A `Magazine` db.Model entity has a db.ReferenceProperty(`Publisher`). I want to get a list of 10 Magazines to display in a table, that has a publisher column populated by model.publisher.name. Am I making 11 queries- one for the Magazine list result, and another one each everytime I reference the .publisher property?

Comment: Read my answer to your previous question. Its relevant also to this.

Comment: Wasn't relevant to either- read my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference property isn't doing queries - it's doing datastore gets, which are faster - but you're correct that it does one per reference you resolve. You can batch them up using [this pattern](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine).

Comment: Nick- I was hoping you'd tackle this one for me-- thanks for the link, I'm not yet sure I understand it completely but if you tell me it's the solution I'll believe you...